# how to pass an array to function parameter in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to add data in my database but i'm stuck here. I'm trying to pass an array but i don't know how to do it and second please help me if there is any other error.  need your expert suggestions thank you.

**controller file**

```
    public function insert(){

            $username= "Hammad";
            $company= "Devlogix";
            $this->load->model('User_model');
            $this->User_model->create_users([
            'username'=> $username,
            'company'=> $company
            ]);
            }

        }
```

**model file**

```
    public function create_users($data){
        $this->db->insert('user', $data);

        }

        }
```

Comment: what's this `i don't know how to do it and second`.

Comment: what's your current output ?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam and second was written mastakenly

Comment: i can't pass array so i was trying something different and it was giving me parse error. but my issue is resolved now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the way

```
controller file
User.php
    public function insert(){

            $username= "Hammad";
            $company= "Devlogix";
            $this->load->model('User_model');
            $data=array(
             'username'=> $username,
            'company'=> $company
            );
            $this->User_model->create_users($data)

            }

        }

model file
user_model.php
    public function create_users($data){
        $this->db->insert('user', $data);

        }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
public function insert() {

    $this->load->model(‘User_model’);

    $data = array(
        ‘username’ => ‘Hammad’,
        ‘company’ => ‘Devlogix’
    );

    $this->User_model->create_users($data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are passing a an array incorrectly.

Try changing the lines:

```
        $this->User_model->create_users([
          'username'=> $username,
          'company'=> $company
        ]);
```

to:

```
        $this->User_model->create_users( array(
          'username'=> $username,
          'company'=> $company
        ) );
```

Comment: Both are same. you can use `[` and `]` to define an array.